# Preserve formatting while creating PDF via iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a rich text box and I have written a code to convert the text into PDF file format to a specific location via iTextSharp. The PDf file is created fine but the problem is with formatting as it doesn't save the formatting (style, images etc.) at all.

Any way I can resolve this issue or if I can't solve it with iTextSharp, what are the other ways to do convert rich text box's text to PDF preserving the images and formatting?

Here's my code where Location is the address with target filename and extension;

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Location, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(dummyRtb.Text));
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and didn't manage to solve it completely, but after some work we got the style clean enough to be sufficient for our customer.

We had to use "stylesheets", which are specific definitions in XML that are applied during rendering (don't confuse them with CSS). It is very basic and error prone, but sufficient for printable clean modules or documents.

We also embedded a QRC code that was computed on the fly, embedding it was not a straight forward task but definitely doable. I cannot give any code as I'm not the proprietor of it, but i can give you this pointer which should lead you down the correct path:

http://www.thiscouldbeuseful.com/2012/04/itextsharp-to-rescue-converting-html-to.html